# Getting an openGL image - runs in simulator, crashes on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios-simulator

The purpose of this function is to return a UIImage from an openGL image. The reason it's being converted to a CG image is so openGL and UIKit elements can be rendered on top of each other, which is taken care of in another function.

The strange thing is, when the app is run in the simulator, everything works fine. However, after testing the app on multiple different iPads, when the `drawGlToImage` method is called on `self`, the app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 error. Does anyone know what I'm doing here that would cause this? I've read that `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` used to have thread safety issues, but it seems like that was fixed in iOS 4.

```
    - (UIImage *)drawGlToImage
{
    self.context = [EAGLContext currentContext];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

    unsigned char buffer[1024 * 768 * 4];
    NSInteger dataSize = 1024 * 768 * 4;

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(currentContext);

    glReadPixels(0, 0, 1024, 768, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &buffer);

    //flip the image
    GLubyte *flippedBuffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(dataSize);

    for(int y = 0; y <768; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x <1024 * 4; x++)
        {
            if(buffer[y* 4 * 1024 + x]==0)
                flippedBuffer[(767 - y) * 1024 * 4 + x]=1;
            else
                flippedBuffer[(767 - y) * 1024 * 4 + x] = buffer[y* 4 * 1024 + x];
        }
    }



    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, flippedBuffer, 1024 * 768 * 4, NULL);
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(1024,768,8,32,1024*4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaLast, ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, -self.view.frame.size.height);

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:iref];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
    free(flippedBuffer);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

When a button is pressed, a method that is called makes this assignment, which causes the app to crash.

```
UIImage *glImage = [self drawGlToImage];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code used to solve it

```
- (UIImage *)drawGlToImage {

    // Code borrowed and tweaked from:
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881143/missing-part-of-the-image-when-taking-screenshot-while-supporting-retina-display

    CGFloat scale = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale;
    CGFloat xOffset = 40.0f;
    CGFloat yOffset = -16.0f;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake((self.chart.frame.size.width) * scale,
                             self.chart.frame.size.height * scale);

    //Create buffer for pixels
    GLuint bufferLength = size.width * size.height * 4;
    GLubyte* buffer = (GLubyte*)malloc(bufferLength);

    //Read Pixels from OpenGL
    glReadPixels(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    //Make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);

    //Configure image
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * size.width;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(size.width, size.height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    uint32_t* pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(bufferLength);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, size.width, size.height, 8, size.width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(iref), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    // These numbers are a little magical.
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, ((size.width - (6.0f * scale)) / scale) - (xOffset / 2), (size.height / scale) - (yOffset / 2)), iref);
    UIImage *outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];

    //Dealloc
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(buffer);
    free(pixels);

    return outputImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in which phase you are calling this method. But before calling any OpenGL functions you need to set the right OpenGL context. In the Xcode template it is this line

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
```

Comment: Can you explain more? I created a context property, added `self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];` to the viewDidLoad method, and `self.context = [EAGLContext currentContext];` `[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];` at the top of the drawGlToImage method. Still getting the same result.

Comment: @Austin Where does the app crash? I also think allocating 3 MB on the stack feels dangerous on a mobile device. How about doing a `malloc` and `free` during the method?

Comment: @Austin Hmm, I also see that `flippedBuffer` is allocated with `malloc` but never `free`'d. Thats a 3 MB memory leak.

Comment: I'll try freeing those. The app crashes when I press a navigation button, which calls a method where the assignment `UIImage *glImage = [self drawGlToImage];` is made. I've set a breakpoint right before that line and everything works up until then. The button pushes on a MFMailComposeViewController. Removing the `UIImage *glImage = [self drawGlToImage];` also prevents the crashing, but this is necessary to create an image to attach to the email in the app

Comment: I updated the code, the same thing still happens. I know it's best practice, but I haven't received any memory usage warnings. Only the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @Austin The debugger should show the exact line that causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Try build for debug if you happen to be building for Release.

Comment: `UIImage *glImage = [self drawGlToImage];` is the exact line causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Was currently building for debug as well

Comment: @Austin That seem strange as I would expect a line in the method `drawGlToImage` to crash, not the call to the method itself (unless the self object is corrupt). The debugger might give you a stack dump, and the line you write is among them, but is there no earlier line within `drawGlToImage`?